# python multiline regex capture

Tags: python-2.7, multiline

I have the following string:

```
hello
abcd
pqrs
123
123
123
```

My objective is to capture everything starting hello and till the first occurrence of 123.
So the expected output is as:

```
hello
abcd
pqrs
123
```

I used the following:

```
output=re.findall('hello.*123?',input_string,re.DOTALL)
```

But the output is as:

```
['hello\nabcd\npqrs\n123\n123\n123']
```

Is there a way to make this lookup non-greedy using `?` for 123? Or is there any other way to achieve the expected output?

Comment: `re.search('[\w\n]+(?=\n123\n{1})', input_string).group(0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`lookhead`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this. You are looking for a group of characters followed by `\n123\n`:

```
import re

input_string = """hello
abcd
pqrs
123
123
123"""

output_string = re.search('[\w\n]+(?=\n123\n)', input_string).group(0)

print(output_string)

#hello
#abcd
#pqrs
#123
```

I hope this proves useful.

Comment: I asked the question just for reference.The string i am working on is NOT necessarily ending in digits, it can be alphanumeric.Is there some simpler way to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you please provide me with more details as to what you mean by "___NOT necessarily ending in digits___"? You can replace `123` with anything of your choosing as long as it's where you are trying to cut your string.